# How to flip thru all pages and back in Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my Jquery datatable I'm programmatically navigating to the pages with setinverval function.

```
  setInterval(function () {

            table3.page('next').draw('page');

        }, 5000)
```

This works fine but stops at last page. Once it reaches to the last page, I want it to go back to the first page and do the whole process again.

I guess I need to find out the count of pages then once it reaches that, go go page 1.  But I have not have good luck on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what I came up with:
http://live.datatables.net/fobalaxe/1/edit

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({paging:true});
    setInterval(function(){browse(table);} , 5000);
 });

function browse(table){

    if(table.page() >= table.page.info().pages - 1){

        table.page('first').draw('page');

    }
    else {
        table.page("next").draw('page');
    }
 }
```